# Detecting whether a generic type argument has an id property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, generic-programming

I'm designing a generic `Slice<E>` class which represents a slice of instances of a set of instances.  For example if we have `Todo` instances, then the slice could represent all the ones that are completed.

If the `Todo` class has an `id` property we would like to set `hasID` to `true` on the `Slice` instance, such that we can also index the `Slice` instance by `id`.  Is there a way to detect at runtime whether the generic argument has and `id` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot here to go on without code.

On the face of it: no, you cannot possibly analyze a generic type argument at runtime since the type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure).  At runtime you can only analyze runtime values, such as the actual objects you pass in to the constructor.  At compile time you can probably make the compiler give a specific `true` or `false` boolean literal type to `hasID` based on the generic type parameter.  And you can do both of those things and hope that you've got a solution where the runtime values actually match up with compile-time types.

Let's try it.  Here's a sketch of a possible solution:

```
class Slice<E> {
  instances: E[]
  hasID: E extends {id: any} ? true : false;
  constructor(firstInstance: E, ...restInstances: E[]) {
    this.hasID = 'id' in firstInstance as Slice<E>['hasID'];    
    this.instances = [firstInstance, ...restInstances];
  }
}
```

The `hasID` property is given a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) that evaluates the `E` type parameter and returns `true` if `E['id']` exists, and `false` otherwise.

The constructor accepts at least one parameter of type `E`, the first one of which is analyzed at runtime for an `id` property in order to set the `hasID` runtime value.

Let's see if it works:

```
const sliceOne = new Slice({a: 1}, {a: 2});
sliceOne.hasID // false at compile time and runtime

const sliceTwo = new Slice({id: 1}, {id: 2});
sliceTwo.hasID // true at compile time and runtime
```

Looks good.  Still there are edge cases you might need to worry about, like:

```
declare const notSure: object;
const oopsie = new Slice(notSure);
oopsie.hasID; // false at compile time, maybe true at runtime!
```

The compiler can't verify that `object` has an `id` property, so it gives `hasID` the type `false`.  But of course an `object` *may* have an `id` property, so maybe `hasID` will be `true` at runtime.  Is there a way to deal with this?  Maybe.  But it's not straightforward.  The question is how likely you are to run into these cases and if you care about them.

Anyway, hope that makes sense and gives you some direction.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - Very nice!  I learned a few new tricks there.  I think that should work fine, as the idea is that Slice users would always declare a type with the `id` property on it.  Thanks again!

Comment: This is for an open source project.  Once I get it tested a bit more I'm going to commit here in case anyone wants a deeper look: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice